# flex-direction в ie11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ie11

Не работает flex-direction:column; в IE11. Перепробывала все возможные префиксы, которые только нашла - ничего не помагает. На картинка-скриншот того как отображается в хром и как в ие. В консоле интернет експлорера flex-direction:column; не зачеркнуто.
Вот код

```
 table{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
        th{
            position: relative;
                padding: 5px 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;

        }
        th.asg-th_sort:after{
            position: absolute;
            top: calc(50% - 8px);
            right: 3px;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            content: '\f0dc';
            display: block;
        }
        tr:nth-child(1n){
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        tr:nth-child(2n){
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }
        tr{
            min-height: 50px;
        }
        td{
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
            position: relative;
        }
        td:before {
                /* Now like a table header */
                position: absolute;
        }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {

        /* flex-table */
        table{
            width: 100%;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flex;
            display: flex;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: none;
        }
        thead {
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: -ms-flex;
          display: flex;
          -ms-flex-negative: 0;
         flex-shrink: 0;
          min-width: min-content;
      }
        tbody {
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flex;
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
        tr {
          display: flex;
          -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
          -webkit-box-direction:normal;
              -ms-flex-direction:column;
                  flex-direction:column;
              -ms-flex-negative: 0;
                 flex-shrink: 0;
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобралась с проблемой. Просто в ie некоректно работабт flex-елементы, когда внутри них вложены елементы с дисплеям таблицы - врод table row и table col.